# How feasible to learn undergraduate math in one year?

Tags: graduate-school, mathematics, online-learning, age

I know that Scott Young tried this for computer science by utilizing resources on OCW.  I am more interested in mathematics (pure and applied).  I wondered how feasible to do the same thing for mathematics.

As for my background, I was in a much worse situation than Scott's.  I received no formal education (primarily for financial reasons) since I was 19.  English is not my native language. And I am 28 now and know very little mathematics (or at least according to my own standards).  All I have is interest and determination.  I worked as a computer programmer for the past years.  Although MOOC was declared failure as revolution since it is criticized to be preaching to the converted, but it does benefit people like me a lot.  I plan to apply to [AMSS](http://www.amss.cas.cn/), a top mathematics graduate school in my country.  The only good thing about the system in my country is that the entrance of a school is only determined by the entrance exam and interview.  This means my lack of college education will have relatively little negative impact on me.  The only thing I worry about is my age.  I feel I am just too old to do anything great.  Look at those wunderkinds who always achieve great things at young ages.  However, five years ago, I audited for half a semester at Fudan university (a school famous for its mathematics program).  I didn't find the *average* math students there are impressive.  I was doing very well for that half semester and students there actually asked me for clarifying some concepts.  Therefore, I do believe I have an aptitude for math.  My goal is really humble and I just want to make a living by doing things I love.

Comment: If it was feasible to learn all of undergraduate math in one year, why would everyone spend 3-4 years doing it?

Comment: To continue with @Dan Romik's comment, even those "wunderkinds" didn't learn all of undergraduate math in one year, at least not the vast majority of them. (However, I did know one person who did this in 18 months -- beginning calculus through standard upper level undergraduate material. He was from China, attended Indiana University's graduate program afterwards for one year 1982-83, then managed to get into the graduate program at MIT.)

Comment: @DanRomik To clarify, my humble goal is just to learn enough undergraduate mathematics in order to be a fully qualified graduate student.  In addition, I am not tabula rasa and I already know some mathematics (calculus, analysis, and linear algebra at the basic level).  If it is two years, I can also accept that.  I'm just afraid of being too old for math.

Comment: What course did you attend at Fudan university? Who were your classmates? Math students or students from other departments? AMSS is one of the best math academy in China. You must be super good to get into. Did you consider other places?

Comment: @LeiZhao you should assume that it would take you at least as long, and probably longer, to study whatever material you want to study, as a full time university student. It can be done with will and determination, but there aren’t any shortcuts. Good luck!

Comment: @scaaahu At Fudan, I audited _Mathematical Analysis_ (it's more like a honor calculus course instead of a proper analysis course) and _Advanced Algebra_ (again, the title is misleading, it is just honor linear algebra using the American terms).  I mean Math students, not students from other department. (I suppose these are freshman courses, a lot of them will transfer to other majors anyway).  I did consider other options like BNU, USTC, Fudan, SHUFE, ECNU.  I can't afford English universities and thus don't consider any of them.

Comment: Thanks for reply. If I were you, I would take two years to study all the textbooks that Fudan Math students would use before they graduate. Get a mentor (preferably a math professor at Fudan) to help you. Once you read all the textbooks and do many of the exercises (very important here), then go to the exam.

Comment: I understand the hardest part of my previous comment is the mentor. But, it's absolutely necessary, don't do this blindly. I let other experts on this site to provide you with better advices. I feel that I am not qualitied for an answer.

Comment: I believe it could be learned in one year, but I also believe there is no reason to try to do it.

Comment: Age is no barrier to further study. You'll be 29 next year regardless of whether you study maths or not.

Comment: It depends heavily on your prior knowledge and skills: maturity is useful, but also any sufficiently systematic and rigorous programming skills (say, arguing about code, not just coding by trouble and error) double as maths skills. I also have the impression that most of what American undergrads learn in 4 years is done in the first 2 years of a German bachelor's, as students don't waste time with proof-less calculus but rather get to jump into the cold water immediately. (Also, lack of required BS classes that only serve to create tenured jobs...)

Comment: @darijgrinberg I have the same feeling for the usual lower division math courses in the US and they are just too easy for qualified Chinese high school graduate. In China, Euclidean geometry is the big subject in middle school and the axiomatic approach and proofs are emphasized. In high school, analytic geometry is the big subject. Vector (as used in the physics, not as element of vector space) and dot and cross product are introduced and vector is used to solve various geometric problems. And various proof techniques (e.g., reductio ad absurdum) are covered. What's taught in US high school?

Comment: @darijgrinberg At the first semester of college, undergraduate students in the STEM fields at a _real_ university are expected to do partial fraction decomposition in order to integrate rational functions. For math students, the first 3 semesters cover the same content of Fichtenholz's 3 volumes in calculus. Why did I say _real_ university? That's because after 1999 act that increase college admission, the quality of college education drops dramatically for a common university. Pretty much like the situation in 70s for the US higher education.

Comment: @darijgrinberg As for my prior background, I was lucky enough to make the most of my secondary education. In high school, I got 2nd prize in National Olympiad in Informatics in Province (yes, Pascal is my first programming language). I later learned Lisp and Scala and did a lot of proofs when learning such languages (esp. for Scala). Interestingly, I learned predicate logic before I was first exposed to the epsilon delta language. This makes it so natural to me. Later, I found a lot of application of logic in various fields (e.g., digital circuits, database). I just have a fetish for logic.

Comment: You did not take part in any exam of calculus and linear algebra so it is difficult to judge your level. You could have a try to solve exercises in this [three hour examination](https://www.ens.psl.eu/IMG/file/SI2015/Sujets%20SCiences/SI-Math%C3%A9matiques%20Principale%20version%20anglaise.pdf) and [another examination](https://www.ens.psl.eu/IMG/file/admission/SI_2016/SIS2016-Maths-Principale-%20anglaise.pdf). It is not expected to solve them all in three hours, but you should be strong if you are able to solve most of them without time limit.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I see that this question is being voted down for being interesting, so let me blacken my own reputation by addressing it.

Mathematics undergraduates do not study mathematics. They study studying, they study structuring their time, they study the work-life balance, they study manipulating their teachers, they study the opposite sex,… and in their spare time they also study mathematics.

As an adult you therefore have a considerable advantage over the children because you have studied all those other subjects and graduated in some of them. That means that unlike them, you can devote 100% of your time to mathematics.

On the other hand, there is a natural pace at which one can learn. Learning is not a conscious process but an unconscious one, and we have very little control over how fast the unconscious mind decides to process things.

Moreover, in mathematics 90% of one’s learning time is completely wasted - the remaining 10# then **more than** makes up for it. When you are learning from people and with people, this process adjusts itself naturally. When learning in isolation, it is not clear that it will. **You do need someone to guide you**. The guidance is not actual tuition (as it would be if you were an 18-year-old child) - more, it is mentoring. Your guide will tell you things like “yes, that concept is difficult” or “this book’s approach does not suit you: try that one instead”.

So think hard about who might be able to guide you. It doesn’t necessarily have to be someone senior. I don’t know enough about your situation and environment to be able to advise.

**BUT** I have read your question a few times and I cannot understand why you are specifically talking about one year. There may be good reasons for it - but without those reasons, it sounds unnecessarily restrictive. You will certainly be able to learn some one-semester subjects in a couple of weeks. But there will be others that will take *far longer* than you expect.

Overall though: the signs are good and don’t worry about being too old!

Comment: +1 for the second paragraph. There is much more to studying as an 18-year old than the subject. It's also often the first time you have to earn your own living (and, even as a mathematics college instructor, I have to say, the non-mathematical skills/friends/sexual experience/hobbies often help you more in life than the mathematical do. I pity every young person who does (and often, has to do) devote their whole life to studying.)

Comment: One year schedule is just tentative. I'll see how things goes and don't mind extending it to two years.  If longer than two years, I will declare myself not a good fit for math and just go back to the computing industry.  One reason for one year is age and another is the fact of being without any income during the time.  You could call both of them status anxiety (old, not working and not formally matriculated, essentially a NEET).

Comment: As for mentor, would you kindly mentor me?  Currently, I almost finish 6.431x on edX. I plan to do quick review of calculus with 18.014 and 18.024, and then start the proper analysis series (18.100C, 18.101).  As for algebra, I plan to do 18.700, 18.701, and 18.702.  If time permitted, I wish to finish Stein's four books on analysis, Zorich's two books, and Godement's four books.  My primary interest for graduate study is mathematical logic and set theory and I want to study with [Qi Feng](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=28529) at AMSS.

Comment: You can also have a look at my own [solutions](https://leeifrankjaw.github.io/notes/probability/6.041SC-PS07.pdf) to the subject I am currently studying.

Comment: ...you must have gone to a different university compared to me as I was busy with my maths degree... Though maybe because I was focused on the university degree I would have liked more content...
Content density will also depend by country and university.

Comment: One thing I would like to expand on as it comes to time spent to learn something is that there are varying depths to which you can know something. If you read through a calculus book as fast as possible you could learn all of the definition, notation, and big results pretty quickly, but you might not be as good at using the ideas to solve problems or prove new theorems as a student who studied the subject for months. And that's okay! You don't need to know everything in-depth, but there will always be more to learn even in subjects you think you already know!